Is it possible to populate list of values in ansible's defaults/main.yml
Having a custom inventory data structures and input arguments of a role, I want to populate those input arguments from inventory data structures. Is it possible to somehow populate list in a loop?
For example, this is inventory structure:
---
install_disk:
  vtbd0:
    scheme: GPT
    target: bsdinstall
    partitions:
      1:
        size: 512k
        type: freebsd-boot
        gptlabel: CSMBOOT
      2:
        size: 55m
        type: efi
        gptlabel: EFIBOOT
        fslabel: efiprtn
      3:
        size: 3g
        type: freebsd-ufs
        gptlabel: UFSBOOT
        fslabel: ufsprtn
      4:
        type: freebsd-zfs
        gptlabel: ZFSMAIN
        poolname: zpool
        ashift: 12
        swapsize: 6G
        mountdir: /tmp/newbsd
        geli:
          algo: AES-XTS
          length: 256
          sector: 4096
          keyfile: zpool.key
          keydir: geli
          keypath: /usr/local
          keycount: 3

And this is how I create a first element of a list:
---
target_dsk:
  dev_name: "{{ install_disk.keys() | first }}"
  prt_scheme: "{{ install_disk.values() | first | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'equalto','scheme') | map(attribute='value') | first }}"
  prt_list:
    - index:  "{{ install_disk.values() | first | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'equalto','partitions') | map(attribute='value') | first | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'equalto',1) |  map(attribute='key') | first }}"
      type: "{{ install_disk.values() | first | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'equalto','partitions') | map(attribute='value') | first | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'equalto',1) |  map(attribute='value.type') | first }}"
      gptlabel:  "{{ install_disk.values() | first | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'equalto','partitions') | map(attribute='value') | first | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'equalto',1) |  map(attribute='value.gptlabel') | first }}"
      size:  "{{ install_disk.values() | first | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'equalto','partitions') | map(attribute='value') | first | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'equalto',1) |  map(attribute='value.size') | first }}"

Maybe somebody can offer more optimal list comprehension? As far as I see mine are not optimal ones.
In any case, I want to know is it possible to populate elements of a list in a loop or in some way to not hardcode the number of list elements in defaults/main.yml?
I've tried to work with dictionary in a straight way, but it doesn't meet my needs on data abstraction level.

Why would you want such a thing?

Input argument of a role are often differ from those in inventory. We should have a way to transform structure of inventory vars to role-arguments structure. I'm looking for this way.

It's fine that they differ right? Ansible is intended that way.

To make my job right and run the immutable role, I need to pull inventory data structure to role one's. The best place to do it is defaults/main.yml.
